# Current drop a certain vds in a transistor

Tags: transistors, current-measurement, fet, device-characteristics

I am measuring the I-V characteristics in a transistor using a 2 channel source measurement unit (SMU) when I change the \$V_{ds}\$ and measure the current while connecting the gate and the source to the SMU and change the \$V_{gs}\$ the current(\$I_{ds}\$) drops at certain \$V_{ds}\$, but when I leave the gate floating the current is normal,

maybe when the Gate and the Source are connected to the SMU there is a connection between them and at a certain point the resistance between the gate and the source drops and the current can pass at a certain \$V_{ds}\$ but when the gate is floating there is no connection and the transistor works properly I don't know if that's correct but has any one faced this problem before or have a better explanation? [image]

Comment: I would take your DUT to the bench a do a sanity check with a supply and multimeter. I have had power transistors go into parasitic oscillation with big long hookup leads when doing I-V tests. I now use ferrite beads on the leads and Bypass where appropriate.

Comment: Did you have the same effect? (the current dropping at at a certain vds for different vgs values) also this happens in different transistors not just one